# Stripe connect onboarding test data for standard accounts

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to follow this document to setup Stripe Connect: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide?platform=web&ui=checkout#create-account-link

At the account link phase it redirects me to Stripe for creating an account etc - for development purposes I would like to skip this instead of entering real data every time.

I came accross this document for testing Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing
It says there is a way to force skip but I don't see anything pop up. Is there a special value I need to pass in to enable the force skip option?

Here are the code snippets I've been using to test account linking

```
const stripe = new Stripe(secrets.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY, {
  apiVersion: "2022-11-15"
});

export class StripeClient {
  /**
   * Create a Stripe account for a user. The account will be associated with the ZCal account
   */
  static accountCreationRequest = async (): Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.Account>> => {
    const account: Stripe.Response<Stripe.Account> = await stripe.accounts.create({
        type: "standard"
      });
    return account;
  };

  static accountLinkRequest = async (stripeAccountId: string): Promise<Stripe.Response<Stripe.AccountLink>> => {
    const accountLink: Stripe.Response<Stripe.AccountLink> = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
      account: stripeAccountId,
      refresh_url: `${config.CLIENT_BASE_URL}/account/integrations`,
      return_url: `${config.CLIENT_BASE_URL}/account/integrations`,
      type: "account_onboarding"
    });
    return accountLink;
  };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "force skip" line on testing Doc is for OAuth flow, which is unrelated to your Onboarding flow, so first let's ignore it.

When you make your first request to create the account, you can [prefill as much information as you want](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standard-accounts#create-account), and it will be automatically populated in the flow later. Here is the full list of [fillable fields](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create).

> You can pre-fill any information on the account, including personal
> and business information, external account information, and more.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use “test data” instead of having to use real data for that account creation flow? Ideally I want to avoid using real data like my real phone number

Comment: The reason I ask is in the [Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-standard-accounts) it explicitly says "OAuth is not recommended for new Connect platforms. We recommend using Connect Onboarding for Standard accounts instead."

Comment: Did you get how to test onboarding with test data and how to avoid it also?